# Admob ads not showing in Android 11

Tags: android, admob, android-11

I'm currently working on an application where I have to set banner and native ads. They are working pretty fine on Vivo and other phones while they are not working(not showing) in my phone which in Infinix. Vivo and Infinix both are android 11.

Comment: You can steal some vivo phone for yourself from public restaurant.

Comment: What is error code you are getting from admob ?

Comment: admob doesn't show any error. but when I launch the app on phone, my phone show where ads are but no ads load

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.